# Ionic 2 serve error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I got the following errors after `ionic serve --lab`:

[image]
Any Idea why the error above is occurred?

> Ionic cli version 3.9.0
>
> App scripts version 1.4.1
>
> Typescript 2.3.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets don't get applied and javascript is not executed, because your browser reports wrong MIME types for these requested documents. They're all sent as text/html.

It seems to be the same problem, as reported [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/refused-to-apply-style-from-http-localhost-8100-build-main-css-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime-checking-is-enabled/121331).

You may try to go to any of the .ts files like *user.ts* or *app.ts* and save them again. This will trigger the automatic build, once finished, your app should run fine again.

Comment: I tried your solution several times and same result

Comment: That's odd. Did you try to reinstall the ionic packages?
    npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I found very similar problems.

Could you try the following:

> Add `<base href="/">` in head before linking all css files
>
> [image]

https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170#issuecomment-386117678

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325#issuecomment-399329033

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue many times.when i close the console and run it again as ionic serve it worked for me properly.Try this once.